# java -Listener/ monitor patches enable/disable function on exists files

Tags: java, swing, button, listener, monitor

Hey i am trying to make a disable, enable depending on existing files(- if file exists turn on). 
I don't know how to add it some event or a process monitor like so ,Need to monitor files, patches, i think it's my concept or some listener??....

Program download files from servers. I need to enable/disable the (swing)button if file is stored/ exist on path. Mby some event listener i have to write but i don't know how to attach it and where..?? or monitor patch and how to do it?? Any idea sugestions?? mby involve md5 or sha cheksum??

Is it possible??

Comment: Are you looking for something like [inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify)?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#newWatchService--

Comment: O watchservice~~ inoty mby it is good idea. And a event on download? on files stop copy or transfer and cheksum would look nice... Would this look nice or each time button is click try to check a cheksum of file. What way would be better and faster or better cheap or what are you opinions sugesstions??